# CoreData - one-to-many modeled relationship ,when i fetch the result , it is nil

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a parent entity called CaseHistory, which can have several instances of MedicationCase entity.

The code like:

```
@interface CaseHistory : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *medicationCaseSet;
@end

@interface MedicationCase : NSManagedObject

@property (retain, nonatomic)CaseHistory *caseHistory;
@end
```

Then, i new a MedicationCase instance, and insert it into the contex, and save it.

```
_tempMedicationCase =  [[BusinessManager sharedInstance].caseHistoryManager newMedicationCase];
 [[BusinessManager sharedInstance].caseHistoryManager insertnewMedicationCase:_tempMedicationCase];

 if(! [_tempCaseHistory.medicationCaseSet containsObject:_tempMedicationCase])
  {
     [_tempCaseHistory addMedicationCaseSetObject:_tempMedicationCase];
  }
[[BusinessManager sharedInstance] save];
```

Then i fetch the result, it is ok, but when i quit the apps, and then fetch old result,it comes NULL.

```
(lldb) po caseHistoryArray
<__NSArrayM 0x20002a80>(
<CaseHistory: 0x200017e0> (entity: CaseHistory; id: 0x20002380 <x-coredata://ADB63B4E-7622-4101-9546-CFA53ACD28E9/CaseHistory/p1> ; data: {
    medicationCaseSet =     (
    );
})
)
```

the contents file is:

```
 <model name="" userDefinedModelVersionIdentifier="" type="com.apple.IDECoreDataModeler.DataModel" documentVersion="1.0" lastSavedToolsVersion="2061" systemVersion="12E55" minimumToolsVersion="Xcode 4.3" macOSVersion="Automatic" iOSVersion="Automatic">
    <entity name="CaseHistory" syncable="YES">
        <relationship name="medicationCaseSet" optional="YES" toMany="YES" deletionRule="Nullify" destinationEntity="MedicationCase" inverseName="caseHistory" inverseEntity="MedicationCase" syncable="YES"/>
    </entity>
    <entity name="MedicationCase" syncable="YES">
        <relationship name="caseHistory" optional="YES" minCount="1" maxCount="1" deletionRule="Nullify" destinationEntity="CaseHistory" inverseName="medicationCaseSet" inverseEntity="CaseHistory" syncable="YES"/>
    </entity>
</model>
```

Comment: Do you use the same Instance of ManagedObjectContext in your BusinessManager and your View (or the class you constructed caseHistoryArray)?

Comment: Assuming that you're using sqlite for storage, I'd start by examining the file content to see whether the problem is not saving objects correctly or not retrieving them correctly.

Comment: Thank you ,sqlite file has stored the result, i have checked it.

Comment: @cortez Thanks for your advice，i have solved it, the reason is that _tempCaseHistory and _tempMedicationCase have different ManagedObjectContext. what i wonder is another things that i build the relationships between the two objects by addMedicationCaseSetObject, the xcode donnot show me any error info,but i use _tempMedicationCase.caseHistory = _tempCaseHistory, the xcode give me the error info.

Comment: Awesome! Glad that I was able to help you.